# How to insert one record of a class to mongodb server c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, class

I have a class AlarmRecord:

```
public class AlarmRecord
    {
        public string AlarmStart { get; set; }
        public string AlarmEnd { get; set; }
        public string AlarmFullJobID { get; set; }
        public string AlarmChannel { get; set; }
        public string AlarmType { get; set; }
        public string AlarmDuration { get; set; }
    }
```

I was wondering how I would do something kind of like this but actually works:

```
var singleRecord = new BsonDocument
        {
            AlarmStart = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            AlarmEnd = null,
            alarmFullJobID = logFullNames[arrayIndex],
            AlarmChannel = $"Channel {channel}",
            AlarmType = alarmTypeDB,
            AlarmDuration = null
        };
db.InsertOne(singleRecord);
```

OR

```
db.InsertOne(new AlarmRecord
{
    --values here--
}
```

I'm basically trying to make values for AlarmRecord each time I want to insert into database, I know I could just insert the values without the class but I feel like this is more organized.
I am also pretty new to programming so please don't flame me lol

Comment: i think you'd benefit from this [beginners tutorial](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/tutorial-mongodb-with-c-the-easy-way-1g68)